# Mysql Function to find total no of seconds between two dates

Tags: mysql

Say i've a from date as 17/10/2012 and to date as 18/10/2012.How will i find total no of seconds that is available ?

**Update** I do not want to select a row which has exceed to date ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _I do not want to select a row which has exceed to date_ You need to clarify what you mean by this...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working demo.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/2869

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-19') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-18') as differece_seconds;
```

"If UNIX_TIMESTAMP() is called with a date argument, it returns the value of the argument as seconds since '1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC."

You can simply use it with date coulmn.
Please check : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are proper `DATE/DATETIME` columns and not the date strings in your question, subtract the values of [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1_column) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2_column) AS difference_seconds
```

If you have stored dates in the string format you posted above (which is a bad idea), you will need [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to first parse them  into proper MySQL dates.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMSTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('17/10/2012','%d/%m/%%Y')) - UNIX_TIMSTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('18/10/2012','%d/%m/%%Y')) AS difference_seconds
```

Comment: :My to date column has only date.I'm storing it in date format.

Comment: @redasaw Doesn't matter if it is `DATE` or `DATETIME`. It will work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to get the seconds since epoch for a specific date. Then just subtract both values.

So assuming the values (in some `DATE` or `DATETIME`) are stored in `col1` and `col2` respectively, use can use something like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( col1 ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( col2 ) AS diff FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: :I always want my output as postive number so we need to perform addition.How do i do this ?

Comment: @redasaw If you want the difference as an absolute (positive) value use the [`ABS` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select timestampdiff(second,'2012-10-16','2012-10-18');
```

output will be 
  172800